# Fast bulk insert from datatable to excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

After filling the datatable from MS SQL table, this is my way to show it in excel. Is there any faster way for doing it?

I think that the recordset option:

> .CopyFromRecordset

is way faster

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal dtTemp As DataTable, ByVal filepath As String)
        Dim strFileName As String = filepath
        Dim _excel As New Excel.Application
        Dim wBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Dim newCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
        Dim OldCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

        OldCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        newCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo( _
            _excel.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(Office.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI))
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture

        wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dtTemp
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            wSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                wSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next
        Next
        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)

        _excel.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get data from an SQL DB into sheets is `=IMPORTDATA("PUT_LINK_HERE")`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Excel interop, the best way to improve performance is to minimize the number of interop calls.  Transferring a rectangular data block to Excel can be done by assigning a two dimension `Object` array to an identically resized `Excel.Range`.  Depending on the amount of data transferred, either doing this as a single transfer or as multiple blocks may be faster due to memory resources consumed.

The following code transfers the data in blocks of rows that allows you to specify the maximum number of rows to transfer per transaction.

```
Public Shared Sub ExportDTBlockMode(dt As DataTable, topLeftCell As Excel.Range, Optional maxRowsInBlock As Int32 = 1000)
    Dim calcMode As Excel.XlCalculation = topLeftCell.Application.Calculation
    topLeftCell.Application.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual

    Dim upperBoundRows As Int32 = Math.Min(dt.Rows.Count + 1, maxRowsInBlock) - 1

    Dim exportArray As Object(,) = New Object(0 To upperBoundRows, 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1) {}

    Dim exportRange As Excel.Range = CType(topLeftCell.Cells.Item(1, 1), Excel.Range)
    exportRange = exportRange.Resize(upperBoundRows + 1, dt.Columns.Count)

    ' create and export header
    Dim header As New List(Of String)
    Dim colIndex As Int32
    Dim rowIndex As Int32 = 0
    Dim arrayRowIndex As Int32 = 0
    For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        exportArray(arrayRowIndex, colIndex) = c.ColumnName
        colIndex += 1
    Next

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrayRowIndex += 1
        colIndex = 0
        For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            exportArray(arrayRowIndex, colIndex) = dr.ItemArray(colIndex)
            colIndex += 1
        Next
        If arrayRowIndex = upperBoundRows Then
            exportRange.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault) = exportArray
            exportRange = exportRange.Offset(maxRowsInBlock, 0)
            arrayRowIndex = -1
        End If
    Next
    If arrayRowIndex > -1 Then
        Dim exportArrayResized(0 To arrayRowIndex, dt.Columns.Count - 1) As Object
        For r As Int32 = 0 To arrayRowIndex
            For c As Int32 = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                exportArrayResized(r, c) = exportArray(r, c)
            Next

        Next
        exportRange = exportRange.Resize(arrayRowIndex + 1, dt.Columns.Count)

        exportRange.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault) = exportArrayResized
    End If
    topLeftCell.Application.Calculation = calcMode

End Sub
```